# Why Does PGmc *smalaz (from PIE *(s)mal-) have "a" (not "o")?

Tags: proto-indo-european, proto-germanic

Why Does PGmc *smalaz (from PIE *(s)mal-) have "a" (not "o")?

Comment: Why should it have _*o_? Long PIE _*ā_ (usually < _eh2_) becomes PG _*ō_, but short _*a_ generally remains _*a_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Why Does Proto-Slavic have long ā malъ?

Comment: That’s a much better question – not one I’m sure anyone knows the answer to (but I’m _not_ a Slavicist!). Derksen chooses to reconstruct a root _*(s)meh₁-_ with a (presumably diminutive) _-lo_ suffix. He posits _o_-grade for the Sl. form, and _e_-grade for Gk _μῆλον_ and OIr _míl_, but zero-grade for Gmc… which of course doesn’t work, because _*sm̥h₁-lo-_ would become _**sumla_. Others have argued that the root is _*(s)melH-_, which works for Gmc, but less so for Gk and OIr, and not for Sl. at all. Perhaps they’re from separate roots, or perhaps there was a metathesis in Gmc…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet zero-grade smh̥1-lo would give the correct Germanic reflex, and it's more typical for the coda of the root to become syllabic in zero-grades

Comment: that said, the reconstruction of this particular root is definitely problematic

Answer (score 2):

Proto-Germanic lacked a robust distinction between the *o & *a vowel qualities.

At an early stage, the two qualities merged, with the short phoneme always being reflected as *a, and the long & overlong phonemes always as *ō and *ô. Later a new *ā developed from earlier *aja sequences, and borrowings, but it was quite restricted.